# jquery id selector with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 divs with the following ID's;

```
- slide0
- slide1
- slide2
- slide3
- slide4
```

I'd like to select them using a variable and id.

```
var clk = 0;
```

The clk is incremented each time the function is ran.

`$('slide' + clk).fadeOut()`<-- How do I make this work?

I'm new to jQuery and in javascript it would have been as simple as;

`document.getElementById('slide' + clk).style`

Comment: you missed # $('#slide'+clk).

Comment: Note that jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: @Boaz you're missing `library` :). it is `javaScript library`

Comment: @VedantTerkar Both statements are not contradictory :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're missing `#`

try

```
$('#slide'+clk).fadeOut();
```

Comment: Oh bloody hell that's embarassing! Thanks!

Comment: if you want to select elements by className use : `$("."+className+"");`. I'm glad that i could help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
   $('#slide'+i).fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var clk = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                $('#slide' + clk).fadeOut();
            }
        });
```